# How to avoid the battery drain while implementing the GPS?

Tags: android

In my app I'm using a GPS listener. I need to turn off the GPS and activate it later. Currently I'm using

`locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);`

to turn off the gps. That will turn the GPS off. But later I'm not able to turn it on? Is there any other methods to turn off the gps?

For activating the GPS I'm using

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, updatesInterval, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: DO u want API to turn on GPS or any other APIS to turn off GPS?

Comment: No. I want to turn on the GPS when the app is launced and wants to turn off the GPS when the app enters background. I'm able to check whether the app is on foreground or background. But donno how to switch off and on the gps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want the gps to return the most accurate value. So I set the minValue and minDistance value of the requestLocationUpdates function to 0.

Then to solve the problem with battery drain I'll start and stop the gps (which is a service) when the app comes to foreground and when the app enters background.

To start the GPS i used

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

in the onCreate of the service.

To end the GPS i used

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

in the onDestroy of the service.

You have to do the starting and stopping of the gps in a service, so that you can start and stop the same instances of the location listener otherwise this thing will go drastically wrong

Comment: I have noticed you have to be very careful, sometimes though it appears onDestroy does not get called, and can cause a rouge gps location listener, sucking down battery. I tried implementing my own class as a singlton, but that did not work b/c the on stop of one activity actually fires after the on start of another... So that does not work. I wish there was an easy solution to make GPS available across the entire application lifecycle, and guarantee to kill it when your done. I guess I could make a list of listeners, and if a user exits, it kills them all... hrrm..

Comment: what if you set the location listener inside a class which extends Application, create it as a singleton, and have access to it from every activity, just by getting the apps instance? Like that u have the gps available across the entire app lifecycle

Answer (score 5):

You can make a service which implement location Listener
so when ever you want to start location listener then you can start service and put

```
ocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, updatesInterval, 0, locationListener);
```

line in onCreate() method

and when you want to close location update the stop service 
and put line

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

to onDistroy() method

Comment: Remember to fine tune **updatesInterval** to optimize battery use.

Comment: updatesInterval is the duration when Location Manager Will Check for the location changed so if You want to optimize battery then just keep updatesInterval value to big so that you can optimize your battery

Comment: Also you can set third argument which is now "0" to big value for battery optimize because Location Manager will updates your location if you cover that much of distance from last Location